# How to apply function on each group and keep same shape of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with categories,I wish to group it by the category variable and then apply some function f(x), where x is a group and returns a 2D array of the same shape of the group.

I wish to apply this function on each group but I need the dataframe to keep the same shape and same index as original dataframe.

I have used the apply function, this apply f on each group quite well but mess with the resulting dataframe index which is now by category, I need the original index that was in original dataframe before applying f, how can I achieve this ?

for example if my input is the following df:

```
1  0.6 A
2  0.2 B
3  0.5 B
4  0.8 A
```

Here I have two groups A and B, I wish to apply a function f(x) for each group and return a group of the same shape, this give me the following output using the apply function

```
A 0.6
A 0.8
B 0.2
B 0.5
```

How can I get back to the old dataframe structure

**Note:** I can't use transform because my function f has to take a group (2D array) as an input and output a whole group (think of fit_transform function of sklearn imputer)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `as_index` and `group_keys` arguments to [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to `False`- this may be what you're looking for:

**as_index**: bool, default True

> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output.

**group_keys**: bool, default True

> When calling apply, add group keys to index to identify pieces.

Without knowing exactly what your function is it's hard to be sure this will do it, but for something like assigning a new column this works well:

```py
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0.6, 'A'], [0.2, 'B'], [0.5, 'B'], [0.8, 'A']])
In [3]: def assign_total_as_col(df):
   ...:     return df.assign(total=float(df[0].sum()))
   ...:
In [4]: df.groupby(1, as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(assign_total_as_col)
Out[4]:
     0  1  total
0  0.6  A    1.4
3  0.8  A    1.4
1  0.2  B    0.7
2  0.5  B    0.7
```

Sorting the index of the resulting frame (with [`df.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)) will give you the result you're looking for, as long as the index you started with was sorted.